# How close do gravitational 2-body hierarchy levels get?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, moons

Due to very few 3-body arrangements being stable (this question thus excluding co-orbital objects like trojans), objects in space usually arrange themselves in a hierarchy of 2-body systems. When the scale difference between these systems is sufficiently large, the arrangements usually have a reasonably good long term stability.

**How close in scale do these hierarchy levels naturally get?**

The Earth-Moon system is pretty large, the moon completing only a bit over 13 orbits in a year. Even closer in scale are the Sun-Jupiter and Jupiter-Kore systems, the outermost moon completing only 5.58 orbits in a Jovian year. The outermost Saturn, Uranus and Neptune moons don't get any closer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The zone of influence of a larger body over a smaller body is known as the hill sphere. Within this sphere the gravitational attraction of the larger body will dominate its satellite and satellites must orbit within the hill sphere of the larger body.

In practice the orbit of a satellite needs to be well within the Hill sphere of its parent to be stable. Orbits at greater than half the hill sphere radius tend not to be stable long term, but orbits within a third of the Hill sphere radius do tend to be stable.

In the case of the Earth all stable satellite orbits must have an orbital period of less than 7 months.

Detailed formula and derivation can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere

Comment: That's technically correct, so I guess there isn't more than that to it.

Comment: I think that it's the best option you will get. The trick is to adjust the orbital parameters and the masses of the stars to ensure the planet doesn't wander to far from star A and that the orbital period of Star A around star B is appropriate.